# Optimal buying strategy for profit based on sale history

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, statistics

This problem came to me recently and I'm struggling to see any good answer. Hopefully someone else will have a valuable insight.

A marketplace sells cards for points with an associated real number value between 0 and 1. The cards have a non-trivial value, i.e. they do not cost 0 points each.

5 of these cards can be combined for points, depending on their averaged values. If their values average to: [0,0.1), 10 points are earned; [0.1,0.5), 5 points are earned; and [0.5,1], 2 points are earned.

Given an arbitrary amount of starting points, what is the optimal card buying strategy to maximise points made over time? Ie: how many points should be paid for a given card value - taking into account owned cards etc?

There is no constraint on the number of 5 card combinations that can be made.

Based on this information, it seems evident a card with an associated 0.15 value should be more valuable than a 0.4 card - the 0.15 card could later be combined with: very low value cards to yield 10 points, or higher value cards to make 5 points easily.

Importantly, the cards available change constantly and there are not enough for sale to necessarily create complete profitable 5 card combinations at any given time. This presents the problem: is it worth purchasing a given card for a certain amount, to save for a later 5, if it's uncertain cards to complete the set will be available.

Does this problem fall into any particular class? And is there a good way to go about determining a good buying strategy based on past card sales?

Thank guys

Comment: What is the cost of each card, and do you have limited funds available for buying cards? If the cost was zero you would obviously just keep buying cards until you had 5 that could make a 10-point combo. Assuming cards do have a non-trivial cost, it seems you would first want to look for a "hand" after each buy that yields an average of 0.1 or lower, but as close to 0.1 as possible since having it lower would be wasteful. Failing that, you would look for a <=0.5 "hand" in the same way. You would submit a 2 hand only when forced. --- just idle speculation, this.

Comment: Doesn't really seem like this question fits on Stack Overflow. Perhaps you should post it on [mathematics.se] instead, although without describing this "marketplace" a bit more it is hard to see how anyone could give a reasonable answer. If there are other agents in this marketplace competing for these cards then `game theory` seems like it might be the most relevant branch of mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll edit the answer to clarify the unclear parts of the question.

Comment: I understand your intuition, however if cards with a low value are much more expensive, than those with a high value, it may only be efficient to make sets scoring 2 points. For instance, in the extreme, cards with a value below 0.1 may never sell for less than 10 points, making a 10 point set always unprofitable.